# Printing even and odd number by two thread

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to print even and odd number using two different thread but It is throwing IllegalMonitorStateException .Kindly suggest me what am I doing wrong .

package com.rishi.threading;

public class MyThread {

```
public static class EvenThread extends Thread {
    Boolean evenFlag;
    Integer sharedCount;

    public EvenThread(Boolean flag, Integer count) {
        this.evenFlag = flag;
        this.sharedCount = count;
    }

    public void run() {

        printEven();

    }

    private void printEven() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            synchronized (evenFlag) {
                if (!evenFlag) {
                    try {
                        evenFlag.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                evenFlag = false;
                System.out.println("even thread :" + sharedCount++);
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class OddThread extends Thread {
    Boolean evenflag;
    Integer sharedCount;

    public OddThread(Boolean flag, Integer count) {
        this.evenflag = flag;
        this.sharedCount = count;
    }

    public void run() {

        printOdd();
    }

    private void printOdd() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            synchronized (evenflag) {
                if (evenflag) {
                    try {
                        evenflag.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                evenflag = true;
                System.out.println("odd thread :" + sharedCount++);
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean evenFlag = new Boolean(true);
    Integer sharedCount = new Integer(0);
    EvenThread thread1 = new EvenThread(evenFlag, sharedCount);
    thread1.setName("evenThread");
    OddThread thread2 = new OddThread(evenFlag, sharedCount);
    thread2.setName("oddthread");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
```

}

I created two thread "EvenThread" and "OddThread".
Both the thread shares two common member variable ie evenFlag and sharedCount.
evenFlag -> just a flag which is set as true when sharedCount is even and set as false when shareDcount is set to odd number.
So both the thread is trying to get lock of evenFlag to control the printing of sharedCount.

Comment: Hint:  Any time you write `synchronized(foobar)`, then `foobar` should be a `final` variable.  It'll save you from making a big mistake.

Comment: Can't I put lock on a particular object (common resource) whose state keeps on changing by individual thread. I want to notify all thread after doing some operation (will change state of common resource during operation) and a particular thread should gain the lock based on the state of the common resource.